# How to add background image to row using bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been attempting to add a background image to a row class from bootstrap 4.1 but have not been able to even have the image display anywhere on the page. Any solution that I have seen online has not worked.

I am using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\overwrite.css">
```

and all of the JS links are at the end of my body tag.

```
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id ="diagL" class ="row text-center">
<div class ="col-sm-6">
  <p id="txtzoom" class ="display-1 font-weight-bold">ART.</p>
</div>
<div class ="col-sm-6">
  <p id="txtzoom" class ="display-1 font-weight-bold text-warning">SCIENCE.</p>
</div>
```

As for my CSS code, I have modified it over and over again in attempts to try to get the image to display

```
#diagL{
 z-index:99;
 position:absolute;
 background: transparent !important;
 background: url("../images/BG/DiagnolL.jpg") !important;
 background: no-repeat !important;
 background: center center;
 background: cover !important;
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Using a different container such as: container, container-fluid, d-flex or simply just div on its own.
- Trying to url() my image differently such as:  url("/images/BG/DiagnolL.jpg") *this is the exact directory copied from "Copy Project Path"*
- Attempting to add the CSS directly to the html inline "style =' ...'"

Note: I have attempted adding a background color to the container and it works perfectly fine but I would ideally like to have the background image display across the entire row container.

At this point, I believe I have tried everything except trying to use javascript but I would not be entirely sure as to how to apply that. If someone could let me know if it is not possible so that I can move on and try something else, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used incorrect `css` properties. Use `background-repeat`, `background-size`, and `background-position` for `no-repeat`, `size` and `position` of background respectively. However, it is better that you use shorthand background.

```css
.row {
  background: url('#path') center / cover no-repeat;
}
```

Most importantly, you should not change `position` of the img and hence remove `position:absolute`. There might be an issue with the `img` path too.

```css
.row {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/The_Sky_Garden.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis excepturi nesciunt facere magni ratione quaerat quo, quisquam blanditiis reiciendis a facilis accusamus ad dolore voluptatibus quam iusto asperiores aliquam nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eos ipsum corrupti dolore dolor placeat maxime, consequatur voluptate unde possimus optio veritatis architecto reiciendis nulla rerum dolorem a, voluptates non.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis sed nobis ratione natus exercitationem dolores suscipit dolore ab voluptatum expedita quo facilis laboriosam, soluta molestias nemo, possimus excepturi nihil odio! Lorem ipsum dolor
      sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas eaque quae id, nam harum assumenda libero molestias aperiam corrupti consequatur, est doloribus vel corporis, ad consequuntur iure tenetur eum commodi!

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Check the code in full screen

---

You may find this post on [`css-tricks`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/) helpful

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it to work but using the same image that you provided from wikipedia. At some point I probably had this code but didn't think it worked because it was my img path that was wrong. How would I then put my img path to use my image since images/BG/DiagnolL.jpg does not appear to work?

Comment: I guess the path you use, is incorrect. It should be relative to `index.html`. Open the img in a web browser, copy its relative path from the address bar and use it.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use

```
background: transparent !important
background: url("../images/BG/DiagnolL.jpg") !important;
```

If I would be you I would check this first.
Transparent backround is before url. Both `!important`
One or other.
Background can not be transparent and visible [`!important` tag] in the same time.
In case of doubt first option goes first, second is ignored.